# Flask/Javascript - How to upload multiple files that were input sequentially?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, file-upload, image-upload

I'm making a basic blogging app in flask, and at the moment I'm trying to add the ability to upload multiple images.

I want to allow people to upload images one at a time sequentially, but when a file is input the value of the input is overwritten.

What combination of Flask or Javascript would allow this to work?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'user_uploads'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
      file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
  return render_template('index.html')
```

---

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input id='file' type='file' accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think I understand your question wrong, however the solution might be that you just want to add "multiple" to your image input, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: why don't you use https://tus.io/demo.html this has way too many ways to upload a file and has resumable uploads as well

Comment: @KimKakanAndersson That's simple enough for me to understand. It's just that, say, the user inputs 3 files at once and then inputs a 4th file separately, the three files are overwritten by the fourth.